# Sitefinity Test Connection Failed

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I am using `vs_2015`, I'm trying to configure connection settings for Thunder inside visual studio. Even after providing correct inputs when I try to test the connection, I get a message `" Test Connection failed"`.
i am trying to install-sitefinity-cms-thunder i installed it but after that when i am trying to configure connection settings for Thunder inside visual studio

> gives me "Test Connection failed error message

I tried more several ways but I didn't get a solution .
[link for what i tried before](https://docs.sitefinity.com/thunder-install-and-upgrade)

and i have another link for the same problem of me 
[here the same problem link](https://www.sitefinity.com/developer-resources/forums/thunder/test-connection-failed-)

any advice, please.

Comment: You need to post here what you have tried.

Comment: [https://docs.sitefinity.com/thunder-install-and-upgrade](here the link for the steps i already did it but still didn't get the solution )

Comment: @WebDevBooster are you got my point and understand what i need ? or need to explain anything else ?

Comment: No, you need to post all of the information (required to understand your question and provide an answer) you need to post ALL of that information right within your question.

Comment: @WebDevBooster i updated my question if that enough or not ?

Comment: This *might* potentially be sufficient (I'm not an expert in this area). In general, on Stack Overflow you want to post all of the information needed to understand your question and provide answers within your question i.e. links to third-party websites are to be avoided unless that's unavoidable. You want your question to be self-contained so that people don't need to click any links.

Comment: Please look into the error/trace logs and provide any relevant errors from there.  Are you using the 'test connection' button? When I did i got an error but after I hit ok it connected fine. Make sure you have installed the thunder module in the correct folder, when picking the folder it should be the source code root.

~/App_Data/Sitefinity/Logs